PySpark / SparkSQL: filter a JSON object on an inner attribute
I have loaded a set of JSON objects in a Spark data frame called t. Inner objects / arrays are parsed and queryable.
Assume one of the inner structures looks like this:
    "identifier": [
        {
            "use": "usual",
            "value": "000021279"
        },
        {
            "use": "official",
            "value": "111222333"
        }
    ],

I can query these values using SELECT identifier[1].value FROM t.
However, the order of this array may vary; use=official may be the first or the second entry. The length of the array can vary as well.
How do I select value where use=official?

Can you explode the array and then filter?

Does this answer your question? How to iterate through an array struct and return the element I want in pyspark
